# ASP.NET Post Get Redirect Browser History Issue

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms, response.redirect

I am using the Post Get Redirect method to submit a form using asp.net webforms.  It's a very simple setup:

```
Step 1) Post form on Page1.aspx
Step 2) Process form and redirect using Response.Redirect to Page2.aspx
Step 3) Page2.aspx redirects using Response.Redirect to Page3.aspx
```

If you are on Page3.aspx and hit the back button, I think it should take you back to Page2.aspx and redirect you right back to Page3.aspx. This would lessen the chance of you  getting back to Page1.aspx and submitting the data again.

Instead, I am being taken straight back to Page1.aspx when I hit the back button.  I have also tried using a 303 Redirect, but that did not work either.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is the right thing to do.

Various browsers, to better support how some sites (like google) operate don't keep a page that redirects immediately in the back history.

Consider this:

1. You search google.com
2. You click on a link
3. This link actually takes you back to google.coms servers before immediately forwarding you to the actual page.
4. You decide that wasn't the right link and click the back button.

At this point, most browsers will take you back to the page identified on step 2.  This is the normally desired and expected behavior of millions of netizens.

To go back to step 3 only to be forwarded on to step 4 would, well, piss some people off.  As certain versions of IE recently did until the behavior was patched.

Point is, the behavior you are seeing is exactly how the rest of the web works.  You should look into some other mechanism to change this, if you really really want to.

**update**

---

@NinjaBomb: Somehow I missed your follow up question, so the following is probably not much use.

The answer is that instead of doing the redirect in c# code you embed some javascript in Page2 that does the redirect when the page load is complete.  The browser then "stores" the reference to page 2.  When they click the back button from 3 it will go back to 2 then redirect on to 3.

Of course, the user could simply hit the back button twice...interrupting 2's redirect and letting them go to 1.  The only other way I can think of is to have page 1, on load, test some session or cookie value to see if they've already been sent on.  If so, then page 1 should do a redirect instead of showing itself.

Comment: Then the question then becomes: how do we force the browser to keep the redirecting page in history? In my case, I think it makes sense.